# Razor - How to attach an id to a radiobutton

Tags: c#, html, css, razor

I am trying to attach an id to my radio button and I'm not to sure how to go about this.

Here is my relevant view code

```
            @foreach (ItemHasParts ihp in item.IHP)
            {
                Part part = db.Parts.Find(ihp.PartID);
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @part.PartIDLink
                    </td>                  
                    <td>
                        @Html.RadioButton("Part", "Harvest")
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.RadioButton("Part", "Transfer")
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.RadioButton("Part", "Dispose")
                    </td>

                </tr>
            }
```

This creates one big radio group for every part that is in the foreach statement. Instead I just want it to be a a radio group for that specific line. So my question is, how can I attach my PartID to the "Part" portion of the radio button?

In this case I would be attaching part.ID to "Part"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*UPDATE*

I solved by casting my partID to a string by doing this

```
 string partID = part.ID.ToString();
```

Then I updated my radio button to look like this

```
 @Html.RadioButton(partID, "Harvest")
```

And it is now working as I expect.